# material-ui jss-rtl - after using jss-rtl my page is still LTR

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, right-to-left, jss

I'm using `material-ui` and `next` and `jss-rtl` in my `react` project but there is a problem
the page is still `ltr` after using `<JssProvider ...>`

-rtl component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from 'material-ui/styles';

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

// Custom Material-UI class name generator.
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

function RTL(props) {
  return (
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      {props.children}
    </JssProvider>
  );
}
export default RTL;
```

-index.js Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme} from 'material-ui/styles';
import r8 from "./components/r8";
import RTL from "./components/RTL";
import appRoutes from "./routes/app";
import "./assets/css/App.css";
import "./assets/fonts/fonts.css";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "PhpPlus"
  },
  pallete: {
    primary: {
      light: r8.color.indigo[300],
      main: r8.color.indigo[500],
      dark: r8.color.indigo[700],
    },
    secondary: {
      light: r8.color.pink.A200,
      main: r8.color.pink.A400,
      dark: r8.color.pink.A700,
    },
    error: {
      light: r8.color.red[300],
      main: r8.color.red[500],
      dark: r8.color.red[700],
    }
  }
});
const Rendering = <RTL>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        {
          appRoutes.map((route, key) => {
            return <Route {...route} key={key}/>;
          })
        }
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
</RTL>;

ReactDOM.render(Rendering, document.getElementById('R8'));
```

### [NOTE] no errors in console

i tested :

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({ direction: "rtl", ...});

//no change , still ltr
```

or

```
<body dir="rtl">
//page direction is rtl but paddings or margins and floats and other css codes not flipped!
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?
Note that this code was working in an earlier version of my project on Windows 10. When I changed my OS into Linux Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) and installed Nodejs, it's not working anymore...
(sorry for bad typing English - I'm Persian! :) )

Comment: somebody help!! :)

Answer (score 13):

I acted in following order:

1. create a `JSS` `Provider` same as you.
2. create a component witch include `JSS` `Provider` in it

I think you need to add some packages to `packagejson` file or maybe update `react` or `material-ui`.

Here is mine:

```
// pagckage.json
...
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.2.3",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-jss": "^8.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
}
...


// the RTL component in separate rtl.jsx file
import React from 'react';
import {create} from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {createGenerateClassName, jssPreset} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const jss = create({plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()]});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

export default props => (
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        {props.children}
    </JssProvider>
);


// Sample for your root component
import React from 'react';
import {MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import RTL from './app/public/rtl';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    direction: 'rtl',
});

const RootComponent = () => (
    <RTL>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <div>
                <TextField label="name"/>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </RTL>
);

export default RootComponent;
```

After these configs I got the `rtl` styles in my project.

Comment: Your answer is exactly right, but I think because of you bad style type you got down vote, I spend 7 hours and could not handle the `RTL` support, the main documentation is very bad for understanding. but with your answer in 15 min I handle it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ali-ghafoori for your answer it helps me :),

BTW there is a solution inside [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#jss-plugins)

```
import { create } from 'jss';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl'

const jss = create({
  plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()],
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      ...
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```