# RTL layout for one item in Material UI for a react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have found this answer
[How to use rtl layout of material-ui next in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919565/how-to-use-rtl-layout-of-material-ui-next-in-react-app)

And also Material UI docs for this issue
https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/

However, does anybody know if it is possible to do for one item only (without changing the theme and body direction)? 
in my case it's  a `Select` item

Comment: Why can't you use [nested themes](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#nesting-the-theme)?

Comment: Too complex and performance consideration

Comment: So what was the performance implication? How much slower was the render? I also don't follow the "too complex" argument. Why is that an issue?